# Number of times ListenerContainerIdleEvent is fired needs some explanation?

Tags: spring-kafka

This question is linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732637/how-to-detect-when-a-spring-kafka-consumer-stops-getting-messages-from-1-partiti).

I have 1 consumer consuming from 1 topic with 3 partitions. I have set the idleEventInterval=30secs. Every 30 secs, I get the following log messages.

> 12:12:51.517 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - No messages received for 30855 milliseconds
>   12:12:51.517 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - No messages received for 30845 milliseconds
>   12:12:51.517 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 1 topic:test-topic
>   12:12:51.517 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 2 topic:test-topic
>   12:12:51.517 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 0 topic:test-topic
>   12:12:51.517 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - No messages received for 30855 milliseconds
>   12:12:51.517 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - No messages received for 30845 milliseconds
>   12:12:51.517 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 1 topic:test-topic
>   12:12:51.517 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 2 topic:test-topic
>   12:12:51.517 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 0 topic:test-topic
>
> 12:13:21.630 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - No messages received for 60977 milliseconds
>   12:13:21.630 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 1 topic:test-topic
>   12:13:21.630 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 0 topic:test-topic
>   12:13:21.630 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - No messages received for 60977 milliseconds
>   12:13:21.630 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 1 topic:test-topic
>   12:13:21.630 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 0 topic:test-topic
>   12:13:21.632 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - No messages received for 60975 milliseconds
>   12:13:21.632 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 2 topic:test-topic
>   12:13:21.633 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - No messages received for 60975 milliseconds
>   12:13:21.633 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.k.InboundMessageHandler - partition: 2 topic:test-topic

The event listener code is -

```
  @EventListener
public void eventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
    LOG.info("No messages received for " + event.getIdleTime() + " milliseconds");

Collection<org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition> partitions = event.getTopicPartitions();
partitions.forEach(p ->
    LOG.info("partition: " + p.partition() + " topic:" + p.topic()));

}
```

1) Why does this event get called 4 times every 30 sec?

2) Why is the partition information not consistent for every set of messages? Sometimes there is no partition information, sometimes partitions are repeated in the same set, etc.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is related to this fixed issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/637? Any chances to upgrade to the latest version of Spring Kafka: https://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/ ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan this is a different event than the one in the bug. Since I posted this question, I read the documentation carefully and came across this "It’s important to understand that the application listener will get events for all containers". I believe this has something to do with the number of events I am seeing. I will run a few more test to understand this further.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the spring-kafka documentation closely and coming across this - "It’s important to understand that the application listener will get events for all containers", I was able to select the right topic and partition idle event based on the assigned partition of the listner. Below code seems to be working well.

Implement the ConsumerSeekAware interface in your listener...and save the partitions assigned to the listen by overriding onPartitionAssigned() method like this -

```
@Override
public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
    assignedPartitions.clear();
    assignments.forEach((topicPartition, aLong) -> assignedPartitions.add(topicPartition.partition()));
}
```

Then in the event listener, select the event only if it is for the concerned topic and partition like this -

```
 @EventListener
public void eventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
    Collection<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = event.getTopicPartitions();
    topicPartitions.forEach(p -> {
        if (p.topic().equals(yourTopicName) && assignedPartitions.contains(p.partition()))
                        LOG.info("No messages on partition: " + p.partition() + " topic:" + p.topic());
         }
    );
}
```

I am not sure why in my case above, the listener was called 4 times...I was expecting it to be called 3 times, once for each partition. I am not observing this behavior in production.